# Why org.hibernate.criterion.Example not working?

Tags: hibernate

I am working with Hibernate ,In that I am using **org.hibernate.criterion.Example** to fetch data It working fine.But ,After adding Boolean property I am not getting values .Please check my code below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

private String name;

private String lname;

private Integer salary;

@Type(type="yes_no")
private boolean newModel; 

@Formula("salary*12")
private Long totalSalary;

}
```

CriteriaExample.java

```
 public class CriteriaExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new  Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setName("Balu");

    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class);
          cr .add(Example.create(user1));

   List list = cr.list();
    System.out.println(list.isEmpty()+".............."+list.size());
}
```

Now I am getting null .But I have 10 records with Balu name in my DataBase,When I remove this

```
         @Type(type="yes_no")
        private boolean newModel;
```

I got records from database.please help me
    this is my query log:

```
select this_.Id as Id1_1_1_, this_.createDate as createDa2_1_1_, this_.updatedOn as      updatedO3_1_1_, this_.address_Id as address8_1_1_, this_.lname as lname4_1_1_, this_.name as name5_1_1_, this_.newModel as newModel6_1_1_, this_.salary as salary7_1_1_, this_.salary*12 as formula0_1_, address2_.Id as Id1_0_0_, address2_.createDate as createDa2_0_0_, address2_.updatedOn as updatedO3_0_0_, address2_.streetName as streetNa4_0_0_ from USER_DETAILS this_ left outer join Address address2_ on this_.address_Id=address2_.Id where (this_.name=? and this_.newModel=?)
```

I didn't set newModel value in my Example object but query created like above,And one thing

when I change boolean to Boolean it's working fine.any one help me

Comment: what is the query generated by hibernate in logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `boolean` can have two values: true or false. It can't be null. So, if you don't set any value for the boolean attribute, its default value is not `null`, it's `false`. So the example query looks for users named "Balu", and having a newModel value of false ("no", in the database). So obviously, if all the users named Balu have a true ("yes") newModel, nothing is returned by the query.

Using a `Boolean` instead of a `boolean` solves the problem, because the default value of a Boolean field is null, and null attributes are ignored when creating an example query.

Note that the query doesn't return null as you're saying in your question. It returns an empty list. That's completely different.

Comment: Thanks for the replay,I got lot of answers from you.Thank you so much